# Pandas pivot table with different conditions in aggfunc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, conditional-statements

Suppose I have `my_df`:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'X': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'Y1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Y2': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'Z': [1, 0, 1, 0]})

my_df
    X   Y1  Y2  Z
0   a   1   1   1
1   a   2   2   0
2   b   3   3   1
3   b   4   4   0
```

I am looking for a way to use `pivot_table` with possibly different conditions on each column in `aggfunc`. As an example, suppose I want to group the data by `X` and get the average. For `Y1` I would like to apply a straightforward `mean` aggregation, while for `Y2` I would like to apply a `mean` aggregation conditional on `Z==1`. The output in this case would be:

```
    Y1  Y2
X       
a   1.5 1
b   3.5 3
```

How can I adjust the following code to accommodate the condition?

```
my_df.pivot_table(index = 'X', aggfunc={'Y1': 'mean', 'Y2': 'mean'})
```

Comment: A simple way would be to first split the table to include just `X, Y2, Z`, remove rows where `Z==0`, then create a pivot table with mean aggregation.

Comment: Agree with @RikkiH `my_df.assign(Y2=my_df.Y2.mask(my_df.Z == 0)).drop('Z', axis=1).groupby('X').mean()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I adjust the following code to accommodate the condition?

One way is `mask` the `Y2` wrt `Z` column and then pivot

```
(my_df.assign(Y2=my_df['Y2'].where(my_df['Z'].eq(1)))
      .pivot_table(index = 'X', aggfunc={'Y1': 'mean', 'Y2': 'mean'}))
```

---

```
    Y1   Y2
X          
a  1.5  1.0
b  3.5  3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this would be doable with `pivot_table` but I can see a way to do it with plain old `groupby`

With `groupby` you can `apply` a function which returns a Series, which will be outputed as a row against your group index.

```
my_df.groupby('X').apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        {
            'Y1':x.Y1.mean(), 
            'Y2':x[x.Z==1].Y2.mean()
        }
    )
)
```

Which returns the expected result.